# How Do I Print Result Of A Void Method To A Jtextarea?

Tags: java, swing

I was wondering how can I resovle my following issue: 
I have a GUI JFrame named My_Frame, and it contains a jTextArea. 
I have another Class named DBConnect witch has a method that prints stuff out of my Database.That method is called getData().
So, I want the output of `getData()` method to be the text of my TextArea.

`jTextArea1.setText(db.getData());` Won't work!

Thanks for your time!

My code for My_Frame:

```
public void jtextArea1(String text) {
System.out.print(text);
    jTextArea1.append(text);     
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new My_Frame().setVisible(true);
            DBConnect db=new DBConnect();
            jTextArea1.setText(db.getData());

        }
    });
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: `db.getData` needs to either accept a parameter of some kind, which it can use to feed the data to or it needs to return some kind of result or needs to feed data in some kind of shared resource, which, after calling it, can be read. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: If your code is to observe standard Java convention, a getter method, one looking like: `getXxx()`, should return something, and so the obvious solution is **not** to make it a void method, but rather have it return something that makes sense.

Comment: I am getting error : void type not allowed here , by the way.

Comment: Again -- don't use a void method there!

Comment: Okay so i found the solution to this. 
I had to remove the static declarator change the method from void to String and that create a reference to the My_Frame class